Supabase Realtime Authentication
Is there a way to authorize supabase realtime with User object as opposed to Session object?
export async function AuthenticatedNavbar({
    initialBalance,
    initialLockedBalance,
    User
}: {
    initialBalance: number
    initialLockedBalance: number
    User: any
}) {

    const supabase = createClient(
        process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL!,
        process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY!
    )

    supabase.realtime.setAuth(User.id)

    const channel = supabase
        .channel(`profile_changes`)
        .on(
            'postgres_changes',
            {
                event: '*',
                schema: 'public',
                table: 'profile'
            },
            (payload) => {
                console.log(`json stuff: ${JSON.stringify(payload)}`)
                const newProfile = payload.new as Profile
                setProfile(newProfile)
            }
        )
        .subscribe()


I have some User object that I am passing through the prop / layout and the user object currently looks like
user: {"id":"2b5a6630-6fbf-4b5f-ae9b-525ce94fdea0","aud":"authenticated","role":"authenticated","email":"nuni@nunimaiil.com","email_confirmed_at":"2024-06-24T06:51:45.746025Z","phone":"","confirmation_sent_at":"2024-06-24T06:51:28.67974Z","confirmed_at":"2024-06-24T06:51:45.746025Z","last_sign_in_at":"2024-07-04T22:21:24.0299Z","app_metadata":{"provider":"email","providers":["email"]},"user_metadata":{"email":"nuni@nunimaiil.com","email_verified":false,"phone_verified":false,"sub":"2b5a6630-6fbf-4b5f-ae9b-525ce94fdea0"},"identities":[{"identity_id":"a94dd1ae-816f-4463-8c60-bbf34a9cd10e","id":"2b5a6630-6fbf-4b5f-ae9b-525ce94fdea0","user_id":"2b5a6630-6fbf-4b5f-ae9b-525ce94fdea0","identity_data":{"email":"nuni@nunimaiil.com","email_verified":false,"phone_verified":false,"sub":"2b5a6630-6fbf-4b5f-ae9b-525ce94fdea0"},"provider":"email","last_sign_in_at":"2024-06-24T06:51:28.661844Z","created_at":"2024-06-24T06:51:28.661921Z","updated_at":"2024-06-24T06:51:28.661921Z","email":"nuni@nunimaiil.com"}],"created_at":"2024-06-24T06:51:28.642064Z","updated_at":"2024-07-07T00:41:57.866135Z","is_anonymous":false}

I tried to pass the ID to supabase.realtime.setAuth() but I am still getting
{"schema":"public","table":"profile","commit_timestamp":null,"eventType":"UPDATE","new":{},"old":{},"errors":["Error 401: Unauthorized"]}
The user should have access to their own profile changes according to how my RLS is configured
Looked at supabase docs but it seems that they all want session / jwt token, but I do not think my site is configured with JWT / session tokens and when I do getSession() it obviously returns null/undefined due to this reason
